# How can I revert to Ubuntu 16.04 login and logged-in themes after installing lubuntu-desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, themes, desktop-environments, login-screen

(This question [has been asked before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366145/how-to-get-the-ubuntu-look-back-after-installing-lubuntu-desktop), but one answer requires me to uninstall `lubuntu-desktop`, and the other is out of date and doesn't work for me.)

I installed `lubuntu-desktop` to see if Lubuntu's reduced memory use would help with an occasional task that tends to crash due to memory constraints. (It does, with nearly ½Gb RAM saved. Ubuntu is quite a memory hog.)

I prefer to use Ubuntu (except when doing that one memory-intensive task). Unfortunately, installing `lubuntu-desktop` has changed both the login screen and the desktop theme — specifically notifications — to the Lubuntu theme.

How can I revert to the Ubuntu theme for both the login screen and when logged in to Ubuntu? Obviously, I wish to retain the ability to switch between Ubuntu and Lubuntu, so I don't want to uninstall `lubuntu-desktop`.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to change the theme or do you want Unity like dash and all in Lubuntu?

Comment: @Raphael The simpler option. I'm happy for Lubuntu to have its own look when I log into it. I would like the login screen and Ubuntu + Unity to look as it did before I installed `lubuntu-desktop`.